# How can my XSLT filter avoid leaving blank lines in output XML when deleting elements, without changing indentation otherwise?

Tags: xml, xslt, filter, blank-line

I am writing an [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) filter which reads an XML file, and generates a shorter XML file with some selected elements (and all their children) removed.

So far, my filter gives me output which is valid, well-formed XML, but it has blank lines where the removed elements used to be. Formally, I think the text node before the removed element remains, causing the blank line. I would like to remove this blank line, *but* leave all other indentation as-is. How can I do this?

A simplified version of my XSLT filter is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/maybe[remove]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A very simplified version of my input XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
      <maybe><keep /></maybe>
   <maybe><remove/></maybe>
</root>
```

Yes, the indentation is non-standard. I'm trying to make the point that I want the filter to leave the indentation it finds, except for the elements it removes. This lets me confirm the result using conventional **diff**.

The output I get now (using `xsltproc` from `libxslt`, on MacOS X 10.10):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
       <maybe><keep/></maybe>

</root>
```

The blank line between `<keep/>` and `</root>` is what I'm trying to eliminate.

Now, elsewhere on SO, related questions *[XSLT: how to prevent the XSLT code from generating redundant blank-space in output xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899687/xslt-how-to-prevent-the-xslt-code-from-generating-redundant-blank-space-in-outp)*  and *[Removing blank lines in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265244/removing-blank-lines-in-xslt)* suggest adding [xsl:strip-space](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-strip-space) to the XSLT filter:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

When I try that, the output file no longer has the blank line, but it now has different indentation than the original:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <maybe>
    <keep/>
  </maybe>
</root>
```

(Note that `<maybe>` and `<keep/>` and `</maybe>` are now on separate lines, and indented differently.)

So, is there an XSLT element which will remove the blank line along with the element, but leave the other indentation and line breaks intact?

Also, my real files are from [GnuCash](http://gnucash.org/) and have a much more complex structure. My real XSLT filter has a more complex match expression. Thus, an XSLT element which doesn't require me to repeat the match expression is preferred.

```
<xsl:template match='gnc-v2//gnc:account[@version="2.0.0"]/act:slots/
        slot[slot:key/text()="import-map-bayes"]/slot:value[@type="frame"]/
        slot/slot:value[@type="frame"]/slot[starts-with(slot:key/text(),
            "Assets, Business, CAD:"
    )]' />
```

Also, a related question *[Removing extra blank lines with XSLT, without using indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33399461/removing-extra-blank-lines-with-xslt-without-using-indentation)* got no answers. No insight there.

I'm using XSLT 1.0 because that's what my tool supports. Does XSLT 2.0 provide a better answer for this question?

*Update*: simplified match patterns slightly, mentioned XSLT 1 vs 2.

Answer (score 4):

**Just add this template**:

```
  <xsl:template match="text()[following-sibling::node()[1][self::maybe[remove]]]" />
```

**The complete stylesheet becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root/maybe[remove]" />
  <xsl:template match="text()[following-sibling::node()[1][self::maybe[remove]]]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note**: I have removed the `indent="yes"` attribute, because this surely messes up (normalizes the indentation of) the output.

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
      <maybe><keep /></maybe>
   <maybe><remove/></maybe>
</root>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<root>
      <maybe><keep/></maybe>
</root>
```

**In case you would also want to remove adjacent preceding comments and/or processing instructions**, then the template to add is:

```
      <xsl:template match=
          "node()[not(self::*)][following-sibling::*[1][self::maybe[remove]]]" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use variables in patterns then I think you need to move to XSLT 3.0 as currently supported by EXSELT or by the commercial editions of the Saxon 9.6 or 9.7.

With EXSLT I have tried the following using variables and keys:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">

    <xsl:key name="version" match="foo" use="@version"/>
    <xsl:key name="item" match="foo/bar/item" use="@key"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vers2" select="key('version', '2.0.0')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="k1" select="key('item', 'k1', $vers2)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="data1" select="$k1/data[starts-with(., 'abc')]"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="$data1| 
                         $k1/text()[not(normalize-space())][some $d in $data1 satisfies ($d is following-sibling::node()[1])]"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

It transforms an input sample of the form

```
<root>
  <foo version="2.0.0">
    <bar>
      <item key="k1">
        <data>abcdefg</data>
        <data>1234567</data>
      </item>
      <item key="k1">
        <data>1234567</data>
        <data>abcdefg</data>
      </item>
      <item key="k2">
        <data>1234567</data>
        <data>abcdefg</data>
      </item>
      <item key="k1">
        <data>foo</data>
        <data>abcdefg</data>
        <data>abcjjjj</data>
        <data>bar</data>
        <data>abcllll</data>
      </item>
    </bar>
  </foo>
  <foo version="1.0.0">
    <bar>
      <item key="k1">
        <data>abcdefg</data>
        <data>1234567</data>
      </item>
      <item key="k1">
        <data>1234567</data>
        <data>abcdefg</data>
      </item>
      <item key="k2">
        <data>1234567</data>
        <data>abcdefg</data>
      </item>
    </bar>
  </foo>
</root>
```

into

```
<root>
  <foo version="2.0.0">
    <bar>
      <item key="k1">
        <data>1234567</data>
      </item>
      <item key="k1">
        <data>1234567</data>
      </item>
      <item key="k2">
        <data>1234567</data>
        <data>abcdefg</data>
      </item>
      <item key="k1">
        <data>foo</data>
        <data>bar</data>
      </item>
    </bar>
  </foo>
  <foo version="1.0.0">
    <bar>
      <item key="k1">
        <data>abcdefg</data>
        <data>1234567</data>
      </item>
      <item key="k1">
        <data>1234567</data>
        <data>abcdefg</data>
      </item>
      <item key="k2">
        <data>1234567</data>
        <data>abcdefg</data>
      </item>
    </bar>
  </foo>
</root>
```

The commercial editions of Saxon 9.6/9.7 (EE and PE) also run the above code and produce the same result as Exselt.

As for using XSLT 3.0 with your real samples, as they seem to have elements in a namespace, the use of `xpath-default-namespace` can simplify that in XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 to have short match patters.

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT filter gives the desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/maybe[./remove]" />
    <xsl:template match="root/text()[following-sibling::maybe[1]/remove]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
       <maybe><keep/></maybe>
</root>
```

However, this approach gets ugly pretty fast as the match expression gets long and complicated. The two template elements have a lot of redundancy in the match patterns. This redundancy can't be helped, however. We can't put the 
common part in a variable. The XSLT 1.0 spec says, "It is an error for the value of the match attribute to contain a VariableReference."

Surely someone else can do better?

Comment: Well, `root/maybe[./remove]` can be shortened to `root/maybe[remove]` for sure. As for eliminating the text nodes, you will have to match them with empty templates as you do, all you can do is to put both (or several) match patterns separated by `|` into a single `<xsl:template match="foo | bar"/>`.

Comment: +1 for the simplification of `[./remove]` to `[remove]`. It's not material to the question, but it is an improvement. Thank you.

Comment: `slot:key/text()="import-map-bayes"` can also be shortened to `slot:key="import-map-bayes"`, unless you are dealing with mixed content inside of the `slot:key` element(s).